# Extract Part of Column Names to Create new Column

Tags: linux, awk

I have the following matrix with columns like this:

```
TRINITY_DN12001_c0_g1_i3^ARC3_ARATH^MORN    1.52    1.20    1.25
TRINITY_DN109651_c0_g1_i1   12.38   32.55   62.98   37.92   9.05
TRINITY_DN26469_c0_g1_i1    1.91    0.00    2.62    2.92    2.22
```

I would like to extract a portion of the first column (TRINITY_DN12001_c0_g1_i3) for each row and use that ID to create a new column. I would like the new matrix to be essentially the same, hust with the IDs extracted from before. I assume I would have to use awk, but not sure how to handle the numbers. I want it to look like this:

```
TRINITY_DN12001_c0_g1_i3 TRINITY_DN12001_c0_g1_i3^ARC3_ARATH^MORN 1.52 1.20 1.25 
TRINITY_DN109651_c0_g1_i1 TRINITY_DN109651_c0_g1_i1 12.38 32.55 62.98 37.92 9.05 
TRINITY_DN26469_c0_g1_i1 TRINITY_DN26469_c0_g1_i1 1.91 0.00 2.62 2.92 2.22
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question and add the expected output.

Comment: Just made an edit.

Comment: Add what you want the file to look like.

Answer (score 1):

Tell me if this works for you:

```
sed 's/\([^\^ ]*\)/\1 \1/' file | tr -s ' '
```

Output:

```
TRINITY_DN12001_c0_g1_i3 TRINITY_DN12001_c0_g1_i3^ARC3_ARATH^MORN 1.52 1.20 1.25
TRINITY_DN109651_c0_g1_i1 TRINITY_DN109651_c0_g1_i1 12.38 32.55 62.98 37.92 9.05
TRINITY_DN26469_c0_g1_i1 TRINITY_DN26469_c0_g1_i1 1.91 0.00 2.62 2.92 2.22
```

Which matches the expected output:

```
TRINITY_DN12001_c0_g1_i3 TRINITY_DN12001_c0_g1_i3^ARC3_ARATH^MORN 1.52 1.20 1.25 
TRINITY_DN109651_c0_g1_i1 TRINITY_DN109651_c0_g1_i1 12.38 32.55 62.98 37.92 9.05 
TRINITY_DN26469_c0_g1_i1 TRINITY_DN26469_c0_g1_i1 1.91 0.00 2.62 2.92 2.22
```

Comment: Some of the new IDs are in the correct column but they are in random columns. I'd like all of the new IDs to be in a new column that is after the first in the original matrix.

Comment: @PatrickThomas Sorry, I'm not sure I unerstand you. My command matches the expected output you posted.

Comment: my apologies. I lost the second piece of code but it works. Thanks a ton. I really appreciate it along with your patience!

Comment: @PatrickThomas Oh I edited it to match exactly... Glad it helped!